# How to parse the numeric portion of a string using d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Say I have a string with the content: `ABC-123`. How do I extract the numeric portion of the string (`123`) using the d3.js library?

Below is a portion of my code currently where I tried to use the `parseInt` function to avail. Note that `ABC-123` exists in a column called `Region` for the purposes of this example:

```
Promise.all([
  d3.csv("abc-data.csv")])

  .then(function(data){
  data[0].forEach(function(d){

  d.Region= parseInt(d.Region);

});
```

What am I missing? I'm using d3.js.v5 if that's helpful. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Regex to only keep the digits in the String, before parsing it :

```js
var d = { Region: "ABC-123" };

console.log( parseInt(d.Region.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10) ); // 123 (Number)
```

If the ID can contain letters, you could `split` it on `-`, and only keep the last part using `pop`:

```js
var d = { Region: "ABC-XYZ-01230Z" };

console.log( d.Region.split('-').pop() ); // "01230Z" (String)
```

And if you want to remove leading zeroes, you can apply `replace` on it:

```js
var d = { Region: "ABC-XYZ-01230Z" };

console.log( d.Region.split('-').pop().replace(/^0+/, '') ); // "1230Z" (String)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Quick question: Does this process inherently make the string a number? If not, how can I easily convert it to a number? Thanks again.

Comment: @R.Baratheon The `str.replace()` part returns a String. That's why I wrapped it with `parseInt` as well

Comment: Got it. This is great. One final question: Is there a way to remove leading zeroes in the process? (E.g., "ABC-012" becomes just "12", etc.)

Comment: Using `parseInt` will give you a Number. Numbers cannot have leading zeroes, so you're fine, there won't be any, unless the Number is actually `0`

Comment: One more question now that I think of it: Say I have a string "ABC-123Z". I only want to drop the "ABC-" portion while retaining that "Z" on the end. What's the best way to go about that? (I realize the resulting string would not be an integer, but wanted to understand the method for achieving this.) Thank you again, blex!

Comment: I edited my answer. Does this help you? Also, Regex can be a little hard to grasp when you're not used to it. The following site may help you understand what each character does _(look on the right)_: https://regex101.com/r/TzEJIi/2